# simple nginx server not working

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx environment and trying to host my first app using nginx.
But I am not being able start the first steps with nginx.

I have seen and read thousands of tutorials on basic nginx setup and have set up basic nginx server block as anyone would have.

Here is my `sites-available/default`

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm ;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

        error_page 400 401 402 403 404 40x.html;
        server_name mydomain.com;

        location / {

                root /var/www/html;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #       # With php7.0-fpm:
        #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

And i have done several deployments with apache but with nginx, i am experiencing peculiar behaviour.

This is how it goes.

- It serves the default nginx welcome page successfully from `/var/www/html`on `mydomain.com`
- Now, if i create a new html file say `test.html` inside `/var/www/html` and try to open `mydomain.com/test.html`, it shows internal server error with no logs in error log or access log.
- Now in my server block, if i add test.html to the index directive as the first option, the same `/var/www/html/test.html` file is served and seen without any error on `mydomain.com` (So that it is clear that there are no problems in file permissions).
- Also, if say i have index as the default index page only, if i add a hyperlink in the default index page, say `<a href="test.html"> Test Page </a>`, and on the default home page served on `mydomain.com` if i click on that hyperlink, `test.html` file is served, but the url in my browser does not change.

I am banging my head on this from last two days and i have tried several things.

- Increased the verbosity of error logs to debug, still nothing shows up in logs
- Tried a hundred other logically same but syntactically different server configurations.

I am pretty experienced with server configurations and have done number of deployments with apache and have never experienced something like this on apache.

Maybe, I am skipping some of the basic concepts of nginx as i do not know much about nginx but felt it would be similar to apache.

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the internal server error?

Comment: It shows 500 internal server error

Comment: The config is good and it should work (I just tested it on my machine). Can you show us your `nginx.conf` file?

Comment: please remove "root /var/www/html;" from location block and replace outside one with "root /var/www/html/;", and yeah please post your nginx.conf file, and are there any other file in sites-available/default, i mean, if are there any other server blocks,?